# Some boys in the class are taller than all the girls?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

```
"Some boys in the class are taller than all the girls"
```

---

**I tried in the following way :**

As it says that some boys are there, means that atleast 1 boy is there who is taller than all the girls .

I think that its propositional logic can be :-

$(∃x)(boy(x) ∧ (∀y)(girl(y) \rightarrow taller(x,y)))$

---

Here 1st AND shows that a boy is must, which implies that at least one boy should be there and 2nd IMPLIES shows that even if class does not have any girl, the property holds good.

Am I right here ?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Does "some boys" mean at least two?  How do we indicate "at least two".  I'm not asking rhetorically.   I actually don't know.

Comment: @fleablood, some boys means atleast one. Actually there must always be a boy who follows the property and I can't account for boy-less class.

Comment: It's OK.  Only nit to be picked: the sentence you wrote is not "propositional logic."  As the title says, it's *predicate* logic.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi, That's really a bad miss from me. I'll correct it :)

Comment: @fleablood I agree -- the phrasing "Some boys..." (with the word "boys" written in the plural) would imply at least two boys in ordinary language. In mathematics, I would expect that such a statement would be rewritten so as to clarify the meaning. Anyway, you can write it in first-order logic as $$(\exists x)(\exists y)\Big(B(x)\land B(y) \land x\ne y \land (\forall z)\big(G(z)\rightarrow (T(x,z)\land T(y,z))\big)\Big),$$ where I've written $B,$ $G,$ and $T$ for the predicates "is a boy", "is a girl", and "is taller than".